# How to loop over list or dict and display in HTML format with f-string

Tags: python, html, smtplib

My code sends email in HTML format when executed.

The received email is basically very simple like:

**Name: somename**

```
sender = 'abc@gmail.com'
receiver = 'xyz@gmail.com'

msg['Subject'] = "Email Subject"
msg['From'] = sender
msg['To'] = receiver

html = f'''\
       <table>
         <tr>
            <td>Name: {name}</td>
         </tr>
       </table>
       '''

send_msg = MIMEText(html, 'html')
msg.attach(send_msg)
s = smtplib.SMTP(;localhost')
s.sendmail(sender, receiver, msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

This works if i have a value of variable, lets say name=Tom. But now I have a list of Names like ['Tom', 'Jack', 'Peter]. How can I loop over this list and pass it to HTML?

Excpected output would be:

Name: Tom

Name: Jack

Name: Peter

Comment: You need to say "msg = {}" before you can add to the dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can compose multiple tr's in a loop:

```
names = ['Tom', 'Jack', 'Peter']
trs = []
for name in names:
    trs.append(f'''\
  <tr>
    <td>Name: {name}</td>
  </tr>''')
table_content = '\n'.join(trs)
html = f'''\
<table>
{table_content}
<table>
'''
print(html)
```

Prints:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name: Tom</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name: Jack</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name: Peter</td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd do it in a loop.

```
names = [
    ('Tom', 'tom@gmail.com'),
    ('Jack', 'jack@gmail.com'),
    ('Peter', 'peter@gmail.com')
]

for name, receiver in names:
    msg['Subject'] = "Email subject"
    msg['To'} = receiver
    html = ...
```

Comment: I have not tried it yet, but wouldn't it send multiple email with separate name? I want one email with all names in the body of received email as expected output in my question. Also I am not trying to send email to different email address. I want all names in my received email body. Yours ans seems like, it's referring to sending email to diff email addresses.

Comment: I assumed you were trying to send multiple emails.  The other answer has the right process -- just concatenate the names to build the body.